# JAVA REGEX :: Could you explain this?

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

My pattern is `[a-z][\\*\\+\\-_\\.\\,\\|\\s]?\\b`

My Result:

> a__
>   not matched
>   a_.
>   pattern matched = a_ 
>   a._
>   pattern matched = a.
>   a..
>   pattern matched = a

why my first input is alone not matched???
Thanks in advance.

[ PS: got the same result with [a-z][\\*\\+\\-\\_\\.\\,\\|\\s]?\\b ]

Comment: why all those backslashes?

Comment: Escapes have escapes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Can you explain in words?

Comment: You don't need to escape meta-characters in word classes (between [])!

Comment: @isnot2bad is right; no need to escape metacharacters in character classes. Your regex could be rewritten as `"[a-z][*+\\-_.,|\\\\s]?\b"`; also, not sure about the last term: didn't you mean to match a space character?

Comment: Sorry about those backslashes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because unlike the period `.`, the underscore `_` is considered to be a word character; so `a_` is one word, but `a.` is a word with interpunction.

So, `a__` matches `a`, then matches `_`, then fails to match a word boundary (since the next `_` is a part of the same word).

`a..` matches `a`, skips the character range, then matches the word boundary between the word `a` and the interpunction `.`.

Comment: hi, Is it prints the WordBoundary also. If so how come the result of my second input is a_   If not how come the result of my 3rd input is  a.

Comment: Your second one detects a word boundary between word-character `_` and non-word-character `.`. Same with the third example, but in reverse (the third example has two words separated by interpunction, the second has a single word `a_` and interpunction).

Answer (score 2):

With the regex rewritten in a "proper way", that is:

```
"[a-z][*+\\-_.,|\\s]?\\b"
```

Or, in an "unquoted", canonical way:

```
[a-z][*+\-_.,|\s]?\b
```

that your first input does not match is expected; a character class will only ever match one character. After it matches the first underscore, it looks for a word boundary, but cannot find one: for the Java regex engine, `_` is a character which can be part of a word. Hence the result.

Comment: Your rewritten regex messed up the `\\s` part. The original regex is `"[a-z][\\*\\+\\-_\\.\\,\\|\\s]?\\b"`, in raw form `[a-z][\*\+\-_\.\,\|\s]?\b` and should be rewritten as `[a-z][*+_.,|\s-]?\b`, and as string literal `"[a-z][*+_.,|\\s-]?\\b"`

Comment: Sorry, but the post has been edited since then; and it was indeed `\\\\s` in the original